# Basis of functions from N to R

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the space of functions $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ does not have a countable basis.

This is a problem I found a few weeks ago and I'm really stuck on it... I haven't thought of a good way to do it so could someone please provide a solution?

Comment: Do you know Cantors countable argument?

Comment: Hint: what do you know about infinite cardinalities? Try comparing the cardinality of $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the cardinality of a real vector space with a countable basis?

Comment: @RobArthan Both cardinalities are the same as cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're getting at with the cardinality thing...

Comment: @i707107: you are right, my error. There is a correct answer to the question on the link in Arthur's comment. I will flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had a countable basis $\mathcal B$ for this space. So every function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ can be expressed as a linear combination (with real coefficients) of finitely many members of $\mathcal B$.  It follows that, for every $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$, there exists a finite set $F\subseteq\mathcal B$ and there exists a natural number $N$ such that $g(n)\leq N\sum_{b\in F}b(n)$ for all $n$.  Since there are only countably many possible $F$'s and only countably many possible $N$'s, we have a countable family of functions $n\mapsto N\sum_{b\in F}b(n)$ that suffice to majorize any $g$.  But this is impossible: Re-index those countably many functions as $\{f_k:k\in\mathbb N\}$ and observe that the function $g$ defined by  $g(n)=1+\max\{f_k(n):k\leq n\}$ is not majorized by any of the $f_k$'s (in fact it eventually majorizes every $f_k$).